# List all word pairs that appear in a line together in a file

Tags: awk, array

How can I use awk to run through a file written as:

```
Sarah,Masha,Helen
Connor,Jessica,Jennifer,Candace
Betty,Sarah,Helen
John,Harold,Frank,Daisy
```

and put out all pairs that appeared in a line together without any repeats (Sarah Helen would appear only once here)?
meaning,

```
Sarah Masha
Sarah Helen
Masha Helen
Connor Jessica
etc.
```

I've been trying to make some kind of for loop but it isn't working for me...

Comment: Does it _need_ to be awk?

Comment: yeah :( @terdon

Comment: Can this be `gawk` or do you need to use non-GNU awk? If `gawk`, which version? The newer ones have some cool sorting functions that can be used for this. Should `Helen Marsha` be considered a dupe of `Marsha Helen`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
% awk -F, '
{
    for(i = 1; i < NF; i++) {
        for(j = i+1; j <= NF; j++) {
            if(length(a[$i,$j]) == 0) {
                if(length(a[$j,$i]) > 0) {
                    next;
                }
                a[$i,$j]=$i" "$j;
                print a[$i,$j];
            }
        }
    }
}' file
Sarah Masha
Sarah Helen
Masha Helen
Connor Jessica
Connor Jennifer
Connor Candace
Jessica Jennifer
Jessica Candace
Jennifer Candace
Betty Sarah
Betty Helen
John Harold
John Frank
John Daisy
Harold Frank
Harold Daisy
Frank Daisy
```

Comment: Congrats on getting to 2K!

Comment: Nice (and congrats indeed), but the OP wants to avoid dupes as well. You have `Sarah Helen` twice.

Comment: Run the output to `awk ... | sort -u`

Comment: @slm not if the names can appear in different order, my understanding is that `Masha Helen` should count as a dupe of `Helen Masha`.

Comment: @terdon - yeah just a thought, not sure if order mattered.

Comment: Yeah I need Masha Helen to count as Helen Masha.... I have no idea how that could be tested :/ @slm

Comment: Thanks @terdon and slm. Updated my answer, fix duplicated.

Comment: Ah yes, the length trick is clever, nice one +1.

Comment: Hi, I noticed you used use of `$i$j` as an index. It is better to use `SUBSEP` ( `$i,$j` ) to exclude the perhaps theoretical possibility that the indexes may "flow" into eachother.

Comment: Hi @Scrutinizer, what do you mean when say `may "flow" to eachother`? Can you give an example?

Comment: I can't think of a proper example with names, but they will probably exist, but to give an example with numbers take 11 and 2. That would produce the same index as 1 and 12, but not if you use SUBSEP.

Comment: yeap, my typo, I used a[$i, $j] in my test. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the names can appear in any order and that `Helen Sarah` should therefore be considered as a duplicate of `Sarah Helen`. If so, this should do what you want. It is very similar to Gnouc's answer but can deal with dupes that appear in different order.

I used a slightly different input file than yours so I could test for more cases:

```
Sarah,Masha,Helen
Betty,Sarah,Helen
John,Harold,Frank,Daisy
Masha,Sarah,Helen,Gerorge
Helen,Sarah,Masha
```

Here's the gawk as a one liner and it's output:

```
$ awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++){if($i > $j){k[$i][$j]}else{k[$j][$i]}}}}END{for(n in k){for (l in k[n]){print n,l}}}' names.txt  
John Daisy
John Frank
John Harold
Sarah Masha
Sarah Betty
Sarah Helen
Frank Daisy
Masha Helen
Harold Daisy
Harold Frank
Helen Betty
```

And here's the same thing broken down:

```
{
    ## For all fields from first to penultimate
    for(i=1;i<NF;i++){
      ## For all fields from second to last
      for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++){
        ## This is to avoid duplicates, $i and $j are names
        ## by comparing (sorting) them, I make sure that they
        ## will be stored in the array consistently so I will
        ## count 'Dick Harry' as a duplicate of 'Harry Dick'
        if($i > $j){
          k[$i][$j]
        }
        else{
          k[$j][$i]
        }
    }
  }
}
END{
    ## Go through the array k tath holds the name pairs
    for(n1 in k){
      ## It is a  2 dimensional array so n1 is the first name
      ## and n2 will be the second
      for (n2 in k[n1]){
          print n1,n2
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: my answer produce the same output with yours. At first, I think a solution like yours, but it doesn't serve the order of input.

Comment: @Gnouc yes, I know they produce the same output (well, different sort order but same information), that's because they're both correct :). I don't see how the sort order (in terms of which line is printed first) could be relevant here, the OP needs to remove duplicate entries so the sort order will change by definition.

Comment: Interesting new feature. The multidimensional array, or rather multiple arrays for every first index, needs gawk 4.x

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
awk -F, '
  {
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      for(j=i+1; j<=NF; j++)
        if(!(A[$i,$j]++*A[$j,$i]++))
          print $i,$j
  }
' file
```