# How can I remove the text from a line after a certain character with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

How can I use `awk` to remove all text after a certain character `;` that appears on every line of my text file? (I then need to run for loops on the text)

```
Jenny,Sarah,John;North Dakota
Henry,Frank;Illinois
Aaron,Kathryn,Caitlin,Harris;New York
```

Answer (score 28):

There are two general approaches.

1. Set `awk`'s field separator to that character. You can then get the parts you want as `$1`:

   ```
   $ echo "Today was cloudy; yesterday too" | awk -F';' '{print $1}'
   Today was cloudy
   ```
2. Use [`gsub()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to substitute it with an empty string:

   ```
   $ echo "Today was cloudy; yesterday too" | awk '{sub(/;.*/,""); print}'
   Today was cloudy
   ```

---

So, for your example:

```
$ awk -F';' '{print $1}' file
Jenny,Sarah,John

Henry,Frank

Aaron,Kathryn,Caitlin,Harris
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's an answer with `sed` -- since you're not really doing any field processing, awk is probably overkill.

```
sed 's/;.*//'
```

Comment: +1 but based on the [OP's comments](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117366/22222), I am assuming this is all part of a larger script. @Jenny, that's the kind of detail you should include in your questions by the way.

Answer (score 5):

And also just `cut` ..

```
cut -d\; -f1 file
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may want to replace all characters after a certain word with another string.  For example:

`original_string="abc blabla foo bar"` and you want to replace words after blabla with 'hello world'

```
echo $original_string | sed -E 's/(.+ blabla) .+/\1 hello world/'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6):**

```
raku -pe 's:g/ \; .*? $$//;'
```

OUTPUTS:

```
Jenny,Sarah,John

Henry,Frank

Aaron,Kathryn,Caitlin,Harris
```

The above code implements the command line `-pe` linewise-autoprinting flags, in conjunction with the well-known `s///` substitution construct. The code tells Raku to `:g` globally search for a `;`, identify `.*?` 0-or-more characters that follow (`?` means non-greedily), up to the end-of-line (`$$`).

(Actually, since the OP seems to indicate that the `;` only occurs once-per-line, the `:g` can be omitted. Also, since the `-pe` command line linewise-autoprinting flags are in use, you can use the `$` end-of-string assertion, instead of the `$$` end-of-line assertion).

The OP seems to indicate that he/she will be running for-loops over the text. This sounds like a simple comma-separated list of names is desired? If so, the following code works:

```
raku -e 'lines.grep(*.chars).map(*.subst(/\; .*? $$/)).join(",").put;'
```

OUTPUTS:

```
Jenny,Sarah,John,Henry,Frank,Aaron,Kathryn,Caitlin,Harris
```

https://raku.org/